# Using circular images for RMPointAnnotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I would like to display circular images as the `annotation` of my Mapbox map. The problem is if I want circular images I need to do it with a `UIImageView`, but I can't set it for an `RMPointAnnotation` because it works with `UIImage` only. Does anybody know how can I achive this?

Is there any alternative to do this on a `RMMapView`?

```
myCircularImageView.layer.cornerRadius =  myCircularImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
myCircularImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Actually I'm using `annotation.image = pinImageView.image;` and it displays the image correctly, but unfortunately it's a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your image has alpha transparency around the circle? Also, you can just use `RMAnnotation` and the `RMMapViewDelegate` method to provide a layer (`RMMarker` or otherwise) for it rather than having `RMPointAnnotation` try to provide it for you.